# Reduce clickable area for link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, resize

I have one word on a page and each separate letter is a link.  I'd like to reduce the size of the clickable area so that there is no space surrounding the letters. Right now it's fine on the left and right of each letter, but there is too much space above and below each letter.  I included a border around the links for illustrative purposes (see fiddle below).

Any ideas on how?

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1><a href=#>H</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>E</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>O</a></h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
        font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
        font-size: 100px;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;

        background-color:blue;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    a {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    div {
        position:absolute; 
        height:100%; 
        width:100%;
        display: table;
    }

    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
    }

    a:visited, a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
           -moz-background-clip: text;
                background-clip: text;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;
        color: white;
    }
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/10/

Comment: This is trickier than it looks, perhaps area coords will help? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

Comment: @lostphilosopher I actually looked into area coords, but I think they only apply to images, not text...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to programminginallston answer you can also add overflow hidden and widen the box, so :

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 180px;
}
```

Although that does clip the H, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks.  the overflow hidden should give me what I want.  The only problem is the potential for cutting things out....

Comment: To complicate things even more.  I'm using web fonts, so if the browser doesn't recognize the font, then the back up font could go outside of the hard-coded bounds.

Answer (score 1):

update your `a` tag css to include

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

You need to change the `display` so that you can work with the box of the element like it is a block, while still allowing it to move inline with the text.  You then change the `line-height` to be only the height of the text.  Browsers typically add a greater `line-height` for readability.

Here is the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QSL6T/

Comment: At first I was like, Sweet! It works!  However, you'll notice that if you mouse over close to each letter, the link is still "activated" even outside of the border.  What's up with that?

Comment: I think you can not get it perfectly right. That is to do with the spacing a font has. So you have to play with the line-height to find the perfect match.

Comment: I don't think this answer is a solution.

Comment: @putvande So you're saying it's the fonts fault and if I change the font the clickable area might be reduced?  Because I've tried multiple fonts and it's all the same.

Comment: Yeah it is 'the fonts fault'. It will not really change with any other font because they probably all have some whitespace. For example, select the text in this comment, you can see there is  some space around it.

Comment: @Khnle I think you're right.  This solution really just changed the border.  It didn't actually reduce the clickable area.

Comment: That's weird.  The inspector says the bounding box is correct but still gives that buggy hover action.  I don't think there is a pure css solution.  You could do something with javascript or images

Comment: Images would be the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there is reserved space for diacritics. If you wanted to show Á or Ç, for instance, there would be no extra space.

A possible workaround is to define `margin-top` to your text and `overflow: hidden` to your container. [Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/18/).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this ?

```
    a {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: block;
        padding-bottom:200px;
        height: 10px;
        width: 150px;
    }
```